# How can I fix ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, automation, anaconda, spyder, pywinauto

I've installed pywinauto via pip in the command prompt (with admin). When run in Microsoft Visual Studio Code, the code runs fine. However, when I attempt to run in Spyder (through anaconda) I am confronted with the error message below. I'm trying to use this script for app automation, but can't seem to get past this first step. I looked up the github and it gave what I believe to be an answer here: [https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32#:~:text=A%20very%20common,version%20%2D%20eg%2C%20%2239%22](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32#:%7E:text=A%20very%20common,version%20%2D%20eg%2C%20%2239%22)), however I don't know how to execute this or if it's the actual answer.

**Code:**

```
   from pywinauto import Application

   app = Application()
```

**Error Message:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users(redacted)\Documents\Canvaauto.py", line 1, in 
from pywinauto import Application # upper 'A'

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywinauto'

Comment: Have you tried to pip install in anaconda command prompt. Search anaconda command prompt, then activate right environment, and then `pip install pywinauto`. That should solve the issue.

Comment: in python code, `print(sys.executable)` you'll get `somepath/python.exe`. then in commandline `somepath/python.exe -m pip install pywinauto `.

Comment: Clearly your `sys.path` is wrong in Spyder, but we have no idea what it looks like when it's either correct or incorrect. Please search for existing questions before asking, then if you still need help, please [edit] to provide enough details at least to tell you where to look next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had determined that the version of python I was attempting to use (3.10) was unsupported by pywinauto and so I tried again with Python 3.8. Thank you to everyone who offered an answer to this.